# how to create a signal consisting of a delay of 1000 samples of zeros?

Tags: matlab, synchronization, signals, signal-processing, delay

How to write the MATLAB code

to create a signal consisting of a 'delay' of 1000 samples of zeros,
followed by variable which i found in previous part 'sss' of 1000 samples and the message I've created 'msg' ?

so there are three variables 'delay' , 'sss' , and 'msg'

please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate them.

```
newSignal = [delay sss msg];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but how do I create a signal consisting of a 'delay' of 1000 samples of zeros ?? Thanks

Comment: delay = repmat(0,1,1000)

Comment: Thanks. appreciate your help. Can I ask you another question here? how do I decode the clean and noisy message ? (It's related to matched filter implementation)

Comment: @palinset I'd say ask another question but make sure you do some searching first. There are a lot of answers here already on noise filtering.